# How to do with INSERT but deny updating some column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6 under Linux.

I have a table of 3 columns (COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3) where COLUMN3 is a 1-char column containing confirmation information Y or N (default is N).

I want to implement a simple maker-checker mechanism.

I want to have STOCKING department staff to have INSERT privilege to add new records.  Then, they can input COLUMN1 and COLUMN2.  They should NOT change the value of COLUMN3.

Then, the ACCOUNTING department staff to have UPDATE privilege on COLUMN3 to update it from N to Y.

However, I found out that, once the new record is inserted, the STOCKING staff can UPDATE the COLUMN3.  Actually, I do not want them to be able to change it.  It should still be using the default value N after the insert.

It seems to me that, once inserting the new records, the user can do everything on every columns of the new record.

The REVOKE action in MySQL cannot help in this situation.

Look like that there is no DENY UPDATE mechanism in MySQL.

Does anyone have similar experience and share a way of how to do so ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be implemented in the front end. Users should not be accessing the db directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have known about [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) statement. Since you have not talked about how you are 'granting' the privileges to your department, I am assuming you might be providing entire database privileges.

There are many privileges you can assign using GRANT statement like Database Privileges, Column Privileges etc. Your requirement shows that you need to assign column privileges which can be done as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1,col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

which will only give INSERT privileges to the user and not update.